# Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath into Eureka server

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, netflix-eureka

I configured Eureka server using java 14 with the following old Maven dependencies:

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
            <artifactId>eureka-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I tried to start the compiled jar I don't have exceptions during start.

I tried to update the dependencies to the latest versions:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
            <artifactId>eureka-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I get exception during startup:

```
2021-05-03 16:56:37.166  INFO 14556 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2021-05-03 16:56:37.834  INFO 14556 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2021-05-03 16:56:37.834  INFO 14556 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2021-05-03 16:56:38.352 ERROR 14556 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.w.WadlApplicationContextImpl   : Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:168) ~[jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:355) ~[jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:508) ~[jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:465) ~[jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:366) ~[jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:107) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:100) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:106) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) ~[jersey-server-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.4.jar!/:1.19.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4566) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:440) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:193) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:402) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.registry.SkyshopRegistryApplication.main(SkyshopRegistryApplication.java:13) ~[classes!/:1.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[skyshop-registry-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[skyshop-registry-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[skyshop-registry-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[skyshop-registry-1.0.jar:1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:72) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122) ~[jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155) ~[jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:165) ~[jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar!/:2.3.0]
        ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? Can you please provide the solution. It would be really heloful.

Comment: Downgrade the version of JAX-B dependencies with some number.